# Getopt recebendo outras opções como argumento

Tags: c, get, entrada-de-dados

Estou fazendo um código que deve receber duas strings pela execução com os parâmetros -i e -o, sendo que ambos podem ser nulos ou não,o problema se encontra quando não é informado o valor de -i, ele recebe -o como argumento.

```
while ((option = getopt (argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1)
switch (option)
  {
  case 'i':      
    value_i = optarg;
    break;
  case 'o':      
    value_o = optarg;
    break;
 default:
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s -i value -o value\n", argv[0]);
exit (1) ;
  }
printf ("value_i =  %s, value_o = %s \n", value_i, value_o);
```

O resultado esperado de ./ler -i -o hello
seria que i = NULL e o = hello, porém resulta em i = -o e o = NULL

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema. Meu programa tem 2 opções obrigatórias (input e output), e cada uma delas deve te rum argumento obrigatório. Tipo: `COMANDO -i argA -o argB <número>`. Só que seu esquecer de fornecer o argumento para o primeiro, ele vai tomar a segunda opção como se ela fosse um argumento... Não sei resolver, infelizmente, mas te entendo.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação [aqui](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) você precisa coloca "::" após a especificacao do argumento para torná-lo opcional.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int option;
  char* value_i = "-1";
  char* value_o = "-1";

  while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "i::o:")) != -1) // <---------
    switch (option)
    {
      case 'i':
        value_i = optarg;
        break;
      case 'o':
        value_o = optarg;
        break;
      default:
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s -i value -o value\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

  printf ("value_i = %s, value_o = %s \n", value_i, value_o);
}
```

Teste:

```
[~]
$./381305 -i -o hello
value_i = (null), value_o = hello 

[~]
$
```